# Use conda envrionment in VScode task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have the following `tasks.json`

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "conda info",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "type conda; which conda",
    },
    {
      "label": "Activate conda envrionment: mkdocs",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "conda",
      "args": [
        "activate", "mkdocs"
      ]
    },
    {
      "label": "Serve mkdocs",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "mkdocs serve --strict --dev-addr localhost:8010",
    },
    {
      "label": "run mkdocs serve in environment",
      "group": "test",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared"
      },
      "runOptions": { 
        "runOn": "folderOpen" 
      },
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": [
        "conda info",
        "Activate conda envrionment: mkdocs", 
        "Serve mkdocs"
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

but running the task always fails because of

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

Even though I have `"python.condaPath"` set and `conda info` tasks shows the correct path.
Moreover when I open a terminal in VScode I can just execute the command.

Note, I am on MacOS.

So how do I use a conda environment in a task?

EDIT:

For completness, here is the corresponding issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/167325 (which is already closed...)